# How ro create correct rewrite rule .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I currently have working rewrite url to rewirite

https://domain/folder/user to https://domain/folder/user.php with the following .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$  %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L,QSA]
```

but when i do https://domain/folder/user/1 and i print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

it show only folder/user instead folder/user/1

can anyone help me with this?

I wish to get folder/user/1 in print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];